# Mutually commuting matrix with $A_i^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be mutually commuting $m\times m$ matrices such that $A_i^2=0$ for all $1\le i \le n$. If $m<2^n$, prove that $A_1 A_2\cdots A_n=0$

---

Since $A_i^2=0$ So $\operatorname{Im}(A)\subset \ker(A) \implies \dim(\ker(A))\ge \frac m 2$ I think we have to use it to prove ..but don't know how go through ...

Comment: I guess you mean $\dim(\ker(A_i)) \geq m/2$!? Probably it is useful to get a bound for $\dim(\ker(A_{n-1}A_n))$ and iterate

Comment: yes right ......

Comment: @Stockfish probably yes but i don't understand how relate this $m<2^n$??

Comment: Not a new question. That follows is a post with $m=n$.  cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880429/pairwise-commuting-nilpotent-matrices-alternative-solution-needed?rq=1

Comment: But the answer there cannot be applied directly here to the case where we have, e.g. m = 15, n = 4. We really should use that the $A_i$ of the current question satisfy $A^2 = 0$ which is much stronger than being 'merely' nilpotent

Comment: Still we could steal some ideas from the answer to that other question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x\in K^m$.

Then $A_1x\in Im(A_1)$, vector space of dimension $\leq m/2$.

In the sequel, $\tilde{U}$ denotes a restriction of $U$.

$\tilde{A_2}:Im(A_1)\rightarrow Im(A_1)$ is $2$-nilpotent. Then $A_2A_1x\in Im(\tilde{A_2})$,

vector space of dimension $\leq dim(Im(A_1))/2\leq m/2^2$, and so on  $\tilde{A_3}:Im(\tilde{A_2})\rightarrow Im(\tilde{A_2})$ is $2$-nilpotent,....

$\tilde{A_n}:Im(\tilde{A_{n-1}})\rightarrow Im(\tilde{A_{n-1}})$ 
 is $2$-nilpotent. Then $A_n\cdots A_1x\in Im(\tilde{A_n})$, vector space of dimension $\leq dim(Im(\tilde{A_{n-1}}))/2\leq m/2^n<1$.

Finally $Im(\tilde{A_n})=\{0\}$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit.**
The answer below seems to be only the partial answer for the particular form of nilpotent matrices.

---

Mutually commuting means that all matrices can be represented simultaneously as, for example, upper triangular.

Of course they are all nilpotent and (*here assumption for the form of matrices*) the first non-zero "mini-diagonal" of this matrix is shifted from the main diagonal at least rounded $m/2$.
(do yourself analysis for dimension $m$ even and odd)

For example matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
0\color{red}\rightarrow & 0\color{red}\rightarrow & 0\color{red}\rightarrow & \color{red}1 & 3 \\
0 & 0\color{red}\rightarrow & 0\color{red}\rightarrow & 0\color{red}\rightarrow & \color{red}2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

has first minidiagonal  (red) shifted by $3$ positions from the main diagonal.

In multiplication values of shifts for such matrices are **added**.
I mean that if $A=A_1A_2$ then shift($A$)=shift($A_1$)+shift($A_2$).

In this case $A^2$ should have to have shift $6>5$ what means that $A^2=0$.

(If shift were by $2$ with $A^2$ result shift would be $ 4$ what is too little to make matrix zero in general case.)

Multiplication $A_1A_2 \dots A_n$ means that   the result matrix has shift at least $nm/2$ what is 
fully fulfilled if $m<2^n$.

Look at some examples.
For $n=2$ we have limit for $m$ equal 3. Result the least shift $3$.

For $n=3$ we have limit for $m$ equal 7.  Result shift $12$

For $n=4$ we have limit for $m$ equal 15.  Result shift $30$,

Always result shift is bigger then $m$ what means that we get zero matrix.

Comment: When you simultaneously triangularize nilpotent matrices , they are strictly upper triangular, but each of them fills the upper part. You do not have the hand on the shape of these matrices.

Comment: @loupblanc  So  would it be only a partial answer for particular form of nilpotent matrices?

Comment: I think that it is difficult to show that we can put our matrices in the form you consider.

Comment: @loupblanc yes, you are right, it is only the answer for some subset of nilpotent matrices, yours is much more precise I hope the OP will transfer the green mark to you..