# Nilpotent Operators Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over an arbitrary field $K$, and let
>   $T_1, \dots , T_n : V \rightarrow V$ be pairwise commuting nilpotent operators on $V$.
>
> (a) Show the composition $T_1 T_2 \cdots T_n = 0$.
>
> (b) Does this still hold if we drop the hypothesis that the $T_i$ are pairwise commuting?

What I have tried: 
I know that for any $T_i$, $\ker({T_i}^n) = \ker({T_i}^{n+1}) = \cdots$. This implies that ${T_i}^n = 0$ for any $i$. I also know that raising each $T_i$ to a power of itself lessens the dimension of the kernel of such a composition. Any help?

Comment: The claim of (b) is false, as you can check by setting $n = 2$ and $T_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $T_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pairwise commuting nilpotent matrices: alternative solution needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880429/pairwise-commuting-nilpotent-matrices-alternative-solution-needed)

Comment: Part (a) is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880429/pairwise-commuting-nilpotent-matrices-alternative-solution-needed .